# Is it possible to create a message extension that allows for picture upload and for mentioning users?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm currently trying to create a message extension for a Teams application and was wondering if it was possible to either mention users or upload pictures in the extension message. For the picture, I was wondering if there was a way to either upload an actual image file or at least paste an image into a text box. I was also wondering if it's possible to mention users in a text box or if it's possible to recreate the functionality similar to the 'Praise' app in Teams that has a dropdown search menu for all the users in the team. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can open a task module from message extension. Provide a field to upload custom image by user. On submit of task module you can display an adaptive card with the uploaded image.

Right now @mentioning a user is available in Adaptive card version 1.2 in developers preview mode. 
So you can take user input in the task module and pass it to the adaptive card.

You can refer the post [How to add a mention in Teams alongside an adaptive card using Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60003127/how-to-add-a-mention-in-teams-alongside-an-adaptive-card-using-bot-framework/60051499#60051499)

Comment: Would you happen to have a link to an example with uploading an image?

Comment: Right now I have a task module that returns an adaptive card form but I can't seem to figure out how to include a field to upload a file. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: You need to render a html page inside task module, with upload image option in it as adaptive card does not support image upload option. On submit of task module(or on click of "Upload image" button), you need to store the image in blob storage(adaptive card requires image to be hosted in public domain). Now create an adaptive card with the image URL and post back to the bot. Here a sample code https://github.com/Wajeed-msft/Appy-ListSearch/blob/master/Source/Microsoft.Teams.Apps.CompanyCommunicator/Views/FileUpload/ImageUpload.cshtml